# should I crawl the aggregate block and pagination in same rules

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to use crawl pagination and aggregate block "each block of ad url"

```
class FiregunsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'centerfireguns'
    allowed_domains = ['centerfireguns.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.centerfireguns.com/firearms.html']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[contains(@class, "i-next")][1]')), follow=True), #if you check start_urls this regex for pagination 
        rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[contains(@class,"product-image")]')), callback='parse_item', follow=True) #and this regex for aggregate block.
    )
```

but only first one rule is running not others.

Comment: What you want to perform exactly?

Comment: Hi, nikhil i want to extract ad urls from page 1, page2, page3.........so is it possible if I use rules for both looping(crawl pagination and get ad url from each page). actually I am new in python.